# how to make without loading the page 2 times I return the correct id in facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, api

because when I use the function getUser () do not get the correct id? receipt is the id of the person logged on to work earlier and I have to reload the page.
how to make without loading the page 2 times I return the correct id?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what is happening, and what you expect to happen.

Comment: excuse my English

what happens is that I'm using php to connect to facebook sdk. and I'm using the function getUser () pra get the id of the user logged on facebook but this does not give me the id correcte but to refresh the page.

happened to me has given me the id of the user connected before me.

Comment: <?php
require("configuracion/inicio.php");
require("../../clases/clase_cliente_store.php");
require("../../clases/clase_general.php");
require ('../../conect/src/facebook.php');



$suscriptores= new ClienteStore ();
$suscriptores2= new ClienteStore();
$general= new General();
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '161615',
  'secret' => '165641616161',
));

Comment: $user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
if($user!=0){ 
if($suscriptores->face_existe($user, $cliente)== true) {
 $suscriptores->autenticar($user, $cliente);
  if($_SESSION['cliente_autorizado']) {
   
   echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">';
   
   echo 'location.href=" bienvenido.php";';
   echo '</script>';
  }
  
} else {

Comment: } else {
    
 echo "Usted No se encuentra registrado en esta aplicacion";
}
}
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Facebook::getUser()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getUser/) (if you use original PHP-SDK) retrieves the details of user from:
* URL arguments
* Cookies set by Facebook JS-SDK or PHP-SDK
* Application session

So unless active session (not Facebook session, but one for your application) present and contain all the details required to identify your user there is no way to know his Facebook's user `id`.

If you not able to get user `id` by calling `getUser` it means non of that data exists at the moment, and you will need to authenticate user:

- Redirect user to URL returned by [`Facebook:getLoginUrl()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/)
- Wait for JS-SDK automatically updates user login status (if `status:true` was passed to FB.init)
- Call `FB.getLoginStatus` (JS-SDK) manually

To be albe to retrieve user's details before loading the same twice you have two options:

1. Increase sessions lifetime in your application
2. Redirect user to URL returned by [`Facebook:getLoginUrl()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/) (well this will load your page twice but the on the first time only redirect will be triggered), authorization flow will just drive user back to your application with all details required for his identification.

Comment: thanks
  The thing is I'm using woobox and from my page I'm running the facebook api sdk and would like that when a user already authenticated simply get your id. but it seems that it happens that cookies facebook saved in this variable because I have the previous user id and not the one currently connected to facebook. to give me the id I have to reload the page Facebbok. and do not know how to prevent this from happening